# Unable to filter the describe instance by tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Unable to filter the instance by tags and get the list of instances.Please help how can i proceed further.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Use the filter() method of the instances collection to retrieve
    # all running EC2 instances.
    filters = [{'Name':'OS_Name', 'Values':['Rstudio']}]  
    #filter the instances
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
    #locate all running instances
    RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances] 
    #print the instances for logging purposes
    #print RunningInstances  
    #make sure there are actually instances to shut down. 
    if len(RunningInstances) > 0:
        #perform the shutdown
        shuttingDown = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=RunningInstances).stop()
        print (shuttingDown)
    else:
        print ("Nothing to see here")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the type of filter so in this case it would be tag. `filters = [{'Name':'tag:OS_Name', 'Values':['Rstudio']}]`

from boto3 docs

tag : - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource. Use the tag key in the filter name and the tag value as the filter value. For example, to find all resources that have a tag with the key Owner and the value TeamA , specify tag:Owner for the filter name and TeamA for the filter value.

Comment: I tried this method tag.filters = [{'Name':'OS_Name', 'Values':['Rstudio']}] but received errors:global name 'tag' is not defined: NameError

Comment: it should be `tag:OS_NAME` not `OS_NAME`

Comment: np! happy to help